# A Destroy Button in the Edit and View for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an app in Rails with a form to edit a register, and I would like to have a destroy button here.

I currently have the button with code that I think should work.
[this is how it looks in the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRCYd.png) and this is the code

```
 <%= link_to t('.destroy', :default => t("helpers.links.destroy")),
                                       register_path(register),
                                       :method => :delete,
                                       :data => { :confirm => t('.confirm', :default => t("helpers.links.confirm", :default => 'Are you sure?')) },
                                       :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-danger' %>
```

But, when I try to delete it says "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in RegistersController#edit"

Comment: did you try using the button_to method in rails? `<%= button_to "delete", {:controller => :name,
      :action => 'destroy', :id => name.id }, :method => :delete %>`

Comment: I don't think it's relevant, but why are you putting the `:confirm` and `:class` options in `:data`? That doesn't look right.

Comment: Where does your destroy action redirect to after destroy?  The error message seems to suggest it goes back to edit where the register object that is being edited has just been destroyed.

Comment: The register is not destroyed at all. When I refresh the edit page it is still there.

Answer (score 0):

try this, write in your `RegistersController#destroy` actin

```
def destroy
 @register = Register.find(params[:id])
 if @register.present?
   @register.destroy 
   redirect_to .....
 else
   redirect_to .... or render 'xyz'
 end
end
```

i thing, error 'ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound' comes because record is not present in the database.